How to add custom validator to the entity fields
In JDL we can define entities and fields and add standard javax validators like min, max, etc. In my scenario I want to add custom valators which i have code templatized in my custom gen erator. but JDL validation does not lt is pass through.
Is there any way custom validator can be added?
I have searched and found Custom annotation supported at Entity level. But how to add for field level custom validation could not found.
Note: I am generating backend Spring boot Java based microservice
